# javascript fade in/out only works with div but not its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a js script that hides/shows elements on a page but it only shows div with the id and won't show the other divs inside that div.

My css :

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}
.content div {
     display: none;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

My js:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Show us the HTML. + What ID are you talking about?

Comment: For demo code, you should use jsfiddle.net.  I have no idea what that domain is, but based on the name, I'll not be visiting it from a work pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must hide only the box div:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content div.box').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

and as the others said you must use the css as:

```
.content > div {}
```

Comment: the yellow is for showing only so you can see it better

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.content > div` instead of `.content div` in your CSS.

It will select only the div directly under the .content, and not every div inside the .content

Answer (score 0):

Confusing question, but I got it.

Use this CSS-selector for nested divs:

```
.content > div {
```

Comment: i have done that the content still wont show here is a pastebin of it http://pastebin.com/bvSYBJnH

Comment: Try to use .attr method instead of .data :
$('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).fadeIn('slow');

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this behaviour better to use some classes or id's instead of tags as `div`

Simplest solution i think will be change css

**From**

```
.content div {
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

**To**

```
.content .box{
     display: none;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

And js will be next :

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.content .box').fadeOut('slow');
$('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

---

If you look into dev console, you will see that script didn't apply `fadeOut` to div's inside div with class `box`. So that why you didn't see content.